# Is there any perf hit using DLL functions?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

As the title says, compared to a normal function, is there a perf hit in calling dll functions? The dll will be loaded by `dlopen`.
EDIT:
Ignore `dlsym` time because I only do it once per each function.

Comment: you don't call it DLL under linux. It is a shared object. The loading of the shared object takes some extra time however once it is loaded it should not make any difference from normal functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calls to DLL functions are indirect by address and the compiler can't inline them, so there is a slight performance hit.

You should only worry if you use them in a performance critical inner loop and after profiling them.

Comment: Ok. Profile it is I'll do! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a performance hit. You do a dlsym call to get the function's address and then call the function with that address. As there is an added dlsym call compared to a function call from the same module, it must be slower. How much that matters? It depends. The only sure way to know is to measure it.

Comment: You are right. But in my case, I only do `dlsym` once for the lifetime of the program for each function. And, additionally I use function pointers to invoke the function. What about then?

Comment: @nakiya In that case you only lose the opportunities of optimization you'd otherwise have if the called function was linked statically, i.e. inlining, inter-procedural optimization, constant propagation and the like. In other words it's really no different from calling a function of the same module through a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out is simply to measure...